# StackOverflow-specific announcements at math.SE

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I got this banner this morning on math.SE:

[image]

This is a StackOverflow podcast and is unlikely to interest people on math.SE... can we ask to not get this sort of thing across all SE websites?

Comment: A related posts on [meta.se]: [Can we reserve the top bar announcements for actual site news?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338766)

Comment: I would support an opt-out feature for such announcements.  StackOverflow podcasts to some extent reflect StackExchange-wide developments.  I hit multiple sites during most days, so I get redundant notifications, but it doesn't seriously hinder me.

Comment: Here is [a Meta StackExchange post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390709/can-we-opt-out-of-the-banner-announcing-stack-overflow-podcasts) proposing an opt-out feature for these system-wide banner announcements.